# Problem reading events, with web3 v1.0 beta 36 and infura

Tags: solidity, web3js, infura

I am trying to read events from a contract already deployed on the blockchain. The event might return uint which is has the indexed property.

First I was using web3 from metamask and worked normally, but I want to use infura now, independently if the user has metamask or not. So I created the websocket but when I try to read I get this error: Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas.

Searching on the web some people say is because the returned value from the event has the property indexed, I could change the contract, but do not feel like I should.

Has anyone else came across this type of error?

I am using vue... The way I am calling the event is:

```
getADN() {
  let ADNCreated = this.$store.state.contractADN().getPastEvents('allEvents', {
      fromBlock:0,
      toBlock: 'latest'
  }, function(error, events){ console.log("error:", error); }).then(function(events){
    console.log(events) // same results as the optional callback above
  });
```

As you can see there is nothing much special about it.

Comment: I have the same issue when using infura and calling contract.methods.balanceOf an ERC20 token, any help?

Comment: Ohh, found the solution here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/60295/smart-contract-error-returned-values-arent-valid-did-it-run-out-of-gas

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in that specific version of *web3.js* (`web3.js@1.0.0-beta.36`). **[1]**
Consider the following complete example, based on the original code snippet:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("wss://rinkeby.infura.io/ws"));

const contractAddress = "0x . . .";
const contractAbi = [ . . . ];
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractAbi, contractAddress);

contract.getPastEvents("allEvents", {
    fromBlock:0,
    toBlock: "latest"
}, function(error, events){ console.log("error:", error); }).then(function(events){
    console.log(events)
});
```

Executing `node events.js` using `web3@1.0.0-beta.36` package returns:

> error: Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?

It has been fixed in the package release after *beta 36*: `web3@1.0.0-beta.37` **[2]**.
Repeating the `node events.js` command, with that newer *web3* beta version, against a valid deployed contract address containing a set of events, is expected to work.

Example output structure:

```
error: null
[ { address: '0x...',
    blockHash: '0x...',
    blockNumber: ...,
    logIndex: ...,
    removed: false,
    transactionHash: '0x...',
    transactionIndex: ...,
    id: '...',
    returnValues: 
     Result {
     },
    event: '...',
    signature: '0x...',
    raw: { data: '0x', topics: [...] } } ]
```

[1] https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1916
[2] https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/releases/tag/1.0.0-beta.37

Stay super!

Javi

Comment: The version issues are hell. Thanks for saving loads of time :)