# Smart Contract Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, rinkeby

Deployed a contract using Remix IDE to Rinkeby testnet.

Etherscan contract address and code is [here](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x30395a22b142a81954015a8183afa1e6ba9a0837#code).

```
contract SimpleCounter {
    int counter;

    constructor() public {
        counter = 0;
    }

    function getCounter() public view returns (int){
        return counter;
    }

    function increment() public {
        counter += 1;
    }

    function decrement() public {
        counter -= 1;
    }
}
```

JavaScript client code:

```
    var contract;

    $(document).ready(function(){
        initContract();
        getCounterValue();
    })

    function initContract(){
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);

        var address = "0xc6482382047fb50e8e7b4658425c9756b28f995c";
        var abi = [
                    ...
                    ];

        console.log('Create contract...');
        contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
        console.log(contract)

    } //initContract()


    function getCounterValue(){
        console.log('getCounter()...');
        contract.methods.getCounter().call().then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log('err...\n'+err);
        });
    }
```

Error:

> Create contract...
>
> (index):86 o {_requestManager: e, givenProvider:
>   MetamaskInpageProvider, providers: {…}, _provider:
>   MetamaskInpageProvider, …}
>
> (index):94 getCounter()...
>
> (index):99 err...
>
> Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?

**NOTE:**

*This works fine in Remix IDE (chrome).*
I'm able to increment/decrement/getCounter... with compiler version:0.4.25+commit.59dbf8f1.Emscripten.clang
.

Why does it fail, when accessing it using '[dist/web3.min.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/tree/1.0/dist)' of Web3.js (Branch 1.0)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I got help from [Veniamin](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1916#issuecomment-428650588).

> I had error "Error: Couldn't decode from ABI: 0x." when call get request with wrong contract address

I made a mistake... I was using 'account address', instead of 'contract address'!

The code works, once correct 'contract address' was used.

Comment: It is worthy of noting that the **address of the contract** is different than the **address of the account that creates the contract** and it is generated when the contract is created.

Comment: i think, every new comer did this mistake. 
it is very confusing to which address is required at what place.

Answer (score 28):

I fixed the similar error by deleting `.json` files from ***build/contracts folder*** and then running `truffle migrate` in the terminal.

However, the error occurred in Visual Studio Code, not Remix IDE.
It appeared after running `truffle migrate --reset`.

I'd like to add to this comment, after you delete `.json` files from ***build/contracts folder*** the problem persisted until I deleted files from the trash  So make sure trash is empty

Comment: @monkrus The issue I had reported was due to *using 'account address', instead of 'contract address'!*. Deleting `.json` wouldn't fix that. You might want to add 'exact problem' along with error - to differentiate 'your scenario' and related fix, for clarity.

Comment: @Ismael Thanks for pointing it out. *To add more clarity*... the issue worked in Remix IDE, but not in custom JavaScript code.

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue and it turned out i was on Metamask Mainnet instead of Rinkeby where my contract was deployed.

Comment: I was not even logged into metamask.

Comment: Switching the network fixed the issue, go for it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to be correct. I think your problem is due to a Web3js bug. Have a look at the issue reported in Github :

https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1916

I recommand you to use [web3.js 1.0.0-beta.35](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta.35) instead.

Comment: Switched to version web3.js 1.0.0-beta.35. But, this time the error is different: `Error: Couldn't decode  from ABI: 0x`.

Comment: Check your contract address

Comment: Already fixed. Have added my answer below. Got help from GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error too. It got fixed after I changed my web3 version to 2.0.0-alpha which was 1.0.0-beta.55 before.

1. So just uninstall your web3 using npm uninstall web3.
2. Then do npm install web3@2.0.0-alpha.

Hopefully, this will fix it for you.

Answer (score 2):

In my case (I'm using Azure blockchain service), I modified my contract file but forgot the build and deploy it again to my Azure blockchain service. Instead, I jump to the `truffle exec` command directly. So, after I re-do those two missing steps, everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me on my react app.

I deployed to contract to Ropsten network, but metamask was using the Rinkeby account. So make sure whichever network you deployed, metamask should be using account from that network.

Another time I had this in next.js. this route is a dynamic route means will fetch the contract by ${contractAddress}:

```
      Router.push(`/campaigns/${recipient}/requests`);
```

instead of `{recipient}` address, I had to put the address of the contract to fetch

Comment: +1 on this. I still had the ropsten Alchemy endpoint configured in my .env file for my react app but forgotten I had redeployed to Rinkeby testnet. This plagued me for nearly 2 days. 
Thank you for suggesting this!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was invoking a "view" method of a contract deployed in local hardhat.

and my nodejs code looks like:  `contract.methods().getterName().call()` and got this error.

I spent hours on this and no luck. At last I switched to Rinkeby Test Network, deploy the contract, and call the "view" method with almost the same code, everything goes well.

so, the solution is:

If you are using HardHat and meet this strange issue, switch to Rinkeby!